# How can i change webkit-slider-thumb color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the input range and it works with CSS, But i want to change the color using javascript. Please help to fix this.

Working CSS

```
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: goldenrod !important;
}
```

Javascript code

```
document.querySelector('.plyr--full-ui input[type=range]').style.setProperty('--plyr-range-thumb-background', 'green')
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the right direction with CSS custom properties (variables). Just change the background to the custom property and set its default color:

```css
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  --plyr-range-thumb-background: goldenrod;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: var(--plyr-range-thumb-background);
}
```

Comment: clean solution ! !